# Using of Backgroundworker in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker

Can anyone explain is it possible to use Backgroundworker in asp.net?
If it's a bad idea, then why?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing good or bad in general, it is all based on how you will use it, and if you will consider any expected future issues,
I find that this article and links inside it is very good 
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

> A few years back Phil Haack wrote a great article on the dangers of
>   recurring background tasks in ASP.NET. In it he points out a few
>   gotchas that are SO common when folks try to do work in the
>   background. Read it, but here's a summary from his post.
>
> An unhandled exception in a thread not associated with a request will
>   take down the process. If you run your site in a Web Farm, you could
>   end up with multiple instances of your app that all attempt to run the
>   same task at the same time. The AppDomain your site runs in can go
>   down for a number of reasons and take down your background task with
>   it. If you think you can just write a background task yourself, it's
>   likely you'll get it wrong. I'm not impugning your skills, I'm just
>   saying it's subtle. Plus, why should you have to?
>
> There's LOT of great ways for you to do things in the background and a
>   lot of libraries and choices available.
>
> Some ASP.NET apps will be hosted in IIS in your data center and others
>   will be hosted in the Azure cloud. The spectrum of usage is roughly
>   this, in my opinion:
>
> General: Hangfire (or similar similar open source libraries) used for
>   writing background tasks in your ASP.NET website Cloud: Azure WebJobs 
>   A formal Azure feature used for offloading running of background tasks
>   outside of your Website and scale the workload Advanced: Azure Worker
>   Role in a Cloud Service scale the background processing workload
>   independently of your Website and you need control over the machine
>   There's lots of great articles and videos on how to use Azure WebJobs,
>   and lots of documentation on how Worker Roles in scalable Azure Cloud
>   Services work, but not a lot about how your hosted ASP.NET application
>   and easily have a background service. Here's a few.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [How to do an BackgroundWorker thread in ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1141831.aspx/1)